# Make all background UI blur after a view pop up

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigationview

I plan to have a pop up view that blur out all the underlying UI behind it after it show, however my background "RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
.background(
Color.white.opacity(0.7)
)" did not show a transparent white or blur like I planned.

```
   var body: some View {
      ZStack() {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack() {
                MyBackGround()
                VStack() {
                      TextField("username", text: $user)
                        .padding()
                        .background(.brown)
                      SecureField("password", text: $pw)
                        .padding()
                        .background(.brown)
                    Button("CONFIRM") {
                        popUp.toggle()
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    .padding()
                }
            }
        }
        if popUp {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .background(
                    Color.white.opacity(0.7)
                )
            MyPopUP()
        }
        }
       }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your popup background is black because by default `RoundedRectangle` is filled with black color, so instead of adding background modifier we need to fill it with that color.

```
NavigationStack {
    // content ...
}
.blur(radius: popUp ? 5 : 0)  // to blur (constant is up to you)
.disabled(popUp)             // bluring does not prevent interaction

if popUp {
    // if semi-transparent background is still needed
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
        .foregroundColor(Color.white.opacity(0.7)) // << here !!

    MyPopUP()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the provided SwiftUI `.blur()` for this context instead.

Add this line of code after your **NavigationStack**.

```
 NavigationStack{...}
      .blur(radius: popUp ? 10 : 0)
      if popUp {
          MyPopUP()
      }
```